# Can we plot heatmaps on top of the other in R?

Tags: r

I have the following empty `ggplot` in `R`, lets call that plot as (***)

```
a = 1:10
b = 1:10
data = data.frame(a,b)
ggplot(data, aes(a, b))
```

Now let us assume that we have also the following three data sets, with the corresponding heatplots

first one,

```
x_1 = 2:6
x_2 = 1:3
x = expand.grid(x_1,x_2)
x_values = runif(15,0,1)
data_1 = data.frame(x_1 = x[,1], x_2 = x[,2],x_values)
ggplot(data_1, aes(x_1, x_2)) +                           
  geom_tile(aes(fill = x_values))
```

second one,

```
y_1 = 4:7
y_2 = 2:9
y = expand.grid(y_1,y_2)
y_values = runif(32,0,1)
data_2 = data.frame(y_1 = y[,1], y_2 = y[,2],y_values)
ggplot(data_2, aes(y_1, y_2)) +                           
  geom_tile(aes(fill = y_values))
```

third one,

```
z_1 = 3:6
z_2 = 8:10
z = expand.grid(z_1,z_2)
z_values = runif(12,0,1)
data_3 = data.frame(z_1 = z[,1], z_2 = z[,2],z_values)
ggplot(data_3, aes(z_1, z_2)) +                           
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z_values))
```

Is there a way to plot all the three heatmaps on top of (***)? I would like to create a plot with x-axis spanning as `a` and y-axis spanning as `b`, and then plot the heatmap for the first data set, on the subspaces with x-axis spanning as `x_1` and y-axis spanning as `x_2`, and on top of that add then add the heatmap of the second data set on the subspace with x-axis spanning as `y_1` and y-axis spanning as `y_2` and do that also for the third data set and to generalize that to much more many data sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what your are looking for:

```r
set.seed(123)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +                         
  geom_tile(aes(x_1, x_2, fill = x_values), data_1) +
  geom_tile(aes(y_1, y_2, fill = y_values), data_2) + 
  geom_tile(aes(z_1, z_2, fill = z_values), data_3) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = range(a)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = range(b))
```

[image]

Comment: Ha ha!. Beat me by seconds as I changed the alpha of the layers to 0.5!

Comment: @AllanCameron Lol. Yeah. Tried with different colored outlines but adding some transparency would probably be the better approach.

Comment: Hey stefan I just noticed that if you change the order of your plots then your outcome changes, and this shouldn't be the case/.

Comment: Hej Jonathan. Yeah. The issue are the tiles where the grids overlap. Hence the final result or at least the coloring will depend on the order in which the grids are plotted. IMHO that could only be fixed by getting rid of the duplicates by using e.g. the mean or the sum of values to color the tiles.